# A User has Paths, which have Blocks

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm wondering if I'm doing this right. I have the following tables

- Users
- Paths
- Blocks

> A Path consists of blocks, A User has one Path, A Block can only belong to one path (so no many-to-many between blocks and paths is needed

This is my **blocks** table

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | path_id | description |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | block 1     |
|  1 |       2 | block 2     |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

I have the following scheme for the **user_paths**

```
+---------+---------+
| path_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

And this is my **user_blocks** table

```
+----------+---------+-----------+
| block_id | user_id | completed |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|        1 |       1 | true      |
|        2 |       1 | true      |
+----------+---------+-----------+
```

This is my 'simplified' scheme in picture

[image]

Now I'm wondering if this is the right way to go about this? Because

- Blocks belong to Paths, but still I'm joining the blocks with the Users table straight.

I feel like this isn't right?

**But otherwise it isn't possible to check wich user has completed which block, right?**

Any idea's or tips?
Thank you!

Comment: 1) If one user *only* has one path, you don't need the `user_paths` table. You just need one `path_id` column on the `users` table. 2) Why do you need the `user_blocks` table? You already have a way to get to them... 3) What's the meaning of the `completed` column in `user_blocks`? It's not specified anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If 2 tables are 1:1, then *probably* they should be a single table.  If 1:many, then 2 tables and the 'many' table has the id of the other table.  many:many requires a 3rd table.

It sounds like you have 1:many, so you don't need the `user_paths` table.

[*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on optimal schema for many:many.

Comment: So as @joanolo mentionned above it should be a path_id on the user column then? Thank you for your answer!